# Python Can classes take arguments?

Tags: python, class, optimization, arguments, code-structure

I have the following class

```
class MetricLst(object):
    def __init__(self,n):
        self.min = min(n)
        self.max = max(n)

lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
p = MetricLst(lst)
print p.max
5
print p.min
1
```

with argument

```
class MetricArg(object):
    def __init__(self,*args):
        self.min = min(args)
        self.max = max(args)

p = MetricArg(1,2,3,4,5)
p.max
print 5
p.min
print 1
```

I have the following questions:

1. if i use MetricArg, is there an elegant way to create the object
   using a list?
2. do i need prefer *args when i create a class (if i can)?

Comment: Just an FYI: `*` is called the _splat_ operator.

Comment: @aviraldg -- I like calling it *splat* too, but I think it's also commonly refered to as the unpacking operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The `*args*` syntax has a mirror calling equivalent:

   ```
   p = MetricArg(*somelist)
   ```

   The elements of `somelist` will be used as arguments to `MetricArg`.
2. That depends on what kind of API you want to present. If you want to accept 0 or more arguments because that's how you expect your class to be called most conveniently, then you use that form.

   In the Python API, the `print()` and the `os.path.join()` functions are well-known examples of callables that use an arbitrary-length parameter list.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a list to a variadic function or constructor

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
p = MetricArg(*L)
```

Whether or not using a variadic function instead of a function accepting a list it really depends on the function.

Will the function/constructor be called often with a dynamically constructed list or will it receive mostly a fixed number of parameters?

If the list is mostly dynamic then accepting a list is the best idea because you will not clutter the code with `*L`. On the other hand if in most cases the number of arguments is fixed in the caller and small then just passing the arguments is more readable than building a list just to pass it.